# Google Keep-like Layout with Polymer

Tags: layout, polymer

I want to make a web app that uses a UI similar to Google Keep. I want to be able to have chips of the same size that can be dynamically added/removed that expand into larger cards with more options. What kind of layout should I use in Polymer?

Here are some quick sketches of what I want to accomplish.

[image: Start page]
[image: An expanded card]

Comment: Pretty broad question. I'd say a `core-header-panel` wiht in it a `core-toolbar` that is tall, so you can scroll. As for the expanding of the element, this should somehow be possible with the `core-transitions`, the `hero` one in specific. Exact implementation I do not know though. You can use the [designer](http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/) to try things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a number of ways you can go, probably best you just try some things & find the approach you like. To help get started I think some of the core-animated-pages demos would help. Here are a couple that you may be able to leverage to get sort of close to your design:

https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gongliang13/polymer/polymer-tutorial-master/components/core-animated-pages/demos/grid.html

https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gongliang13/polymer/polymer-tutorial-master/components/core-animated-pages/demos/music.html

Comment: dead links :( @sfeast

Comment: Hmm looks like they did away with these when moving to Polymer 1.0. I think the most similar behavior is here - https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animated-pages&view=demo:demo/index.html I also updated the previous links with some working ones.